# (MID: 7207702) - Journey Builder for Apps SDK Explorer not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

I am trying to create my own field app using Journey Builder for Apps SDK Explorer (https://github.com/ExactTarget/JB4A-SDK-Android/tree/master/JB4A-SDK-Explorer). My intention is to use the Apps SDK Explorer base for my new application to be developed as technology proof of concept

I have setup the development environment in Eclipse and was trying to Build / Run it. However, I am getting following errors.

[2015-01-18 20:44:50 - SDK_ExplorerHomeActivity] Dx 
trouble processing "javax/security/cert/CertificateException.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
[2015-01-18 20:44:50 - SDK_ExplorerHomeActivity] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2015-01-18 20:44:50 - SDK_ExplorerHomeActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

The build is successful but I get the error when I am trying to run the application. This could be because of any jar file but the application uses many.

Could anyone from support please help me?

Regards,
Vineet

Comment: The "Dx 1" error usually points to a misconfiguration in your JAR files.  Take a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2681165/617044 and validate your setup with the instructions here: https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/journey-builder-for-apps/sdk-implementation/register-your-devices.html

Answer (score 2):

I had 2 copies of android.jar included in the project. It seems it got included while importing project. I removed the duplicate from Android Private Libraries where only third party jars are kept. This resolved the issues.

Thanks @Bill for your help.

Regards,
Vineet